# What type can be used with annotations which won't affect static type checkers

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, pyright

I'd like to use Python (3.12) type annotations at runtime for my own purposes that have nothing to do with variable typing. The syntax is very convenient for adding metadata to variables.

So I'd like to annotate with a type that won't affect any static type analysis that may also be occurring. The annotation [PEPs](https://peps.python.org/pep-0593/) make reference to uses like mine (i.e., using annotations for things other than static type analysis), and in particular [`Annotated`](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec/qualifiers.html#annotated) is close to what I need. The problem is that I'd like to skip the first argument to `Annotated` since I don't actually want to associate a type with an object—I just want to associate metadata.

Is there a type (or can one be built) that won't alter static type analysis? I know `Any` is a reasonable choice, but that changes static type analysis. For example, [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) assigns variables with no type annotation the type `Unknown` (not `Any`).

Comment: What does your code currently looks like, and what do you want it to be?

Comment: It's currently `type JustAnExample = Any` and then `SOME_CONSTANT: JustAnExample = 0`. This works fine (I can see the annotation at runtime) but it forces me to add the `Any` type to `SOME_CONSTANT` which is not the same as leaving it without a type (from the point of view of pyright for example)

Comment: What observable difference does it make to you whether you annotate something with `Any` or leave it unannotated or annotated with `Unknown`?

Comment: From pyright's docs: "If a symbol’s type cannot be inferred, Pyright sets its type to 'Unknown', which is a special form of 'Any'. The 'Unknown' type allows Pyright to optionally warn when types are not declared and cannot be inferred, thus leaving potential 'blind spots' in type checking". So one example is that this optional warning wouldn't work if I declare a variable `Any` instead of leaving it unannotated

Comment: I see. So you could try to access the `Unknown` type somehow and use that (however at a first glance I would have no clue how to do that since Pyright itself is not written in Python).

Comment: Yeah I drew the same conclusion :) and it would be pyright-specific

Answer (score 0):

While not wanting to use type annotations for annotating types suggests an XY problem to me, the most logical way to do this would be with type variables:

```
from typing import Annotated, get_args, TypeVar, Generic

Ta = TypeVar('Ta')
Tb = TypeVar('Tb')
Tc = TypeVar('Tc')

class Test(Generic[Ta, Tb, Tc]):
    a: Annotated[Ta, {'my-app': 1}]
    b: Annotated[Tb, {'my-app': 2}]
    c: Annotated[Tc, {'my-app': 3}]

_, my_app_data = get_args(Test.__annotations__['a'])

print(my_app_data['my-app']) # 1
```

I haven't tried pyright, so I don't know if that supports [PEP 695](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/), but if it does, you could simply write out your annotations like so:

```
from typing import Annotated, get_args

class Test[Ta, Tb, Tc]:
    a: Annotated[Ta, {'my-app': 1}]
    b: Annotated[Tb, {'my-app': 2}]
    c: Annotated[Tc, {'my-app': 3}]
```

Either way, it's important that within a single class or function, all variables with potentially different types get their own type variable.

Comment: Aha that's interesting, it does seem like `Generic` wouldn't imply anything about the type while still letting me annotate. Having to give different variables a different generic type wouldn't work in my application though. I was hoping to have a simple and easy way to tag a bunch of variables without changing anything else about the code or its static type analysis.

Answer (score -1):

```
from typing import Annotated, Any

# Annotate a variable with metadata using Annotated with Any
my_variable: Annotated[Any, "metadata_key"] = "value"

# Access the metadata associated with the variable
metadata_value = my_variable.__annotations__["metadata_key"]
print(metadata_value)  # Output: "value"
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid associate the `Any` type with any variables, since that is different than leaving a variable with no type associated.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__annotations__'.` `__annotations__` is available on functions for annotated arguments and classes for annotated attributes. Also, that is not how the second argument to `Annotated` works _or_ how you access the metadata.